Do I save on cost/efficiency by having multiple GSIs use the same PK in DynamoDB?
I have a DynamoDB table with multiple posts that I want sortable by:

likes
views
comments

The Table looks like this:



PK
SK
type
PK1
SK1
PK2
SK2
PK3
SK3




POST#1234#
POST#INFO#
post
SORT#POST#VIEWS#
312
SORT#POST#LIKES#
005
SORT#POST#COMMENTS
132


POST#3112#
POST#INFO#
post
SORT#POST#VIEWS#
153
SORT#POST#LIKES#
426
SORT#POST#COMMENTS
065


POST#6526#
POST#INFO#
post
SORT#POST#VIEWS#
525
SORT#POST#LIKES#
233
SORT#POST#COMMENTS
121


USER#bob1#
USER#INFO#
user
SORT#USER#FRIENDS#
012
SORT#USER#UPLOADS#
012




POST#6526#
POST#DETAILS#
post-details









I have 3 GSIs (I like to use generic key names so I can reuse them in different ways for other documents).
MY GSIs currently looks like this:

GSI1: PK1 + SK1
GSI2: PK2 + SK2
GSI3: PK3 + SK3

But PK1, PK2, and PK3 never change and are only being used because of the typical convention. It would be just as beneficial for me (and it would actually be more human-readable) to reuse the type as the GSI-PK.
I would prefer My GSIs to look like this:

GSI1: type + SK1
GSI2: type + SK2
GSI3: type + SK3

I know I'll still need to have 3 GSIs but I'm wonder if doing it this way has any other benefit other than simplification. Does it save on indexing somehow? Is there a better (more "single table design"?) way of sorting the same documents filtered by type?
My access patterns are:

1 specific post by PK
a list of posts sorted by

likes,
comments
or views.


1 specific user by PK
a list of users sorted by:

friends
uploads




It's impossible to talk about data modelling on DynamoDB without knowing your access patterns

@LeeroyHannigan I've added a table that may help explain. My access patterns are: getting 1 specific post by PK - or - a list of posts sorted by likes, comments or views.

How many posts do you expect per PK?

the table you show is invalid.  The PK+SK are the same for rows 1 and 2.  (And row 3 is only different by missing the trailing # )

@LeeroyHannigan 1 post per PK. There may be more info per PK (See SK:POST#DETAILS#). I've added other data as an example. For my real-life work, there is a tremndous amount of information per post. Same with user-history. This is why I'm modeling my data this way.

@Charles My apologies. I tried using a simple example for stackoverflow rather than my real data and I missed some spots. I've flushed it out more

No, you won't save any cost - think of each GSI entry as a separate, automatic write. It'll cost the same regardless of what the key structure is.
You probably don't want to use the type as a PK though, because that'll concentrate your data into a small number of partitions (the number of types you have). A good PK has a lot of values, ideally well distributed - that's what lets DynamoDB scale. Unfortunately this makes DynamoDB a poor choice for things like "sort all posts by views" since to answer that question you actually do want all the posts under the same PK (so you can query them). Thus, you won't get a big benefit from DynamoDB and you might want to consider a different datastore. If you do want to use DynamoDB and you have a lot of data, you might want to do something clever like choosing a partition key that's floor(views / 100) or something, to bucket posts into multiple partitions.
